# Basket Analysis in Powerpivot - Sum of two products' revenue

Tags: powerpivot, market-basket-analysis

I want to calculate sum of two products' revenues (Product A & B) which are sold in one order whereas the guidance available to me is with respect to calculating revenues of only `product b` attached to `product A`. 
Formula i am currently using is:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [SALES_AMT] ),
    CALCULATETABLE ( SUMMARIZE ( Sales, [GLOBAL_CONTRACT_ID] ), ALL ( Product ) ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Sales[SKU_NUM], 'Filter Product'[Filter SKU NO] )
)
```

Comment: What is the structure of your tables? could you edit your question to include a basic example of your data and the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro for replying.

Comment: http://www.daxpatterns.com/basket-analysis/ Data structure in the link is  what exactly I am trying to use.    I am only able to find revenue of products selected in product slicer where  a certain product selected in filter product slicer is sold in an order using above formula. Is there anyway I can calculate sum of both product and filter product revenue,sold in same order.